# Google Pie Chart not show in Blade Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-pie-chart

I am trying to display the data with google pie chart. Everything works normally when running on localhost, but not in hosting. I've debugged and no errors were found. I am using Laravel 8.83.16

My Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $dealers = Dealer::paginate(20);
        $count_dealers = DB::table('dealer_gesits')->count();

        $data_dealer = Dealer::select(
                DB::raw('province as province'),
                DB::raw('count(*) as number')
            )
            ->groupBy('province')
            ->get();
        $array[] = ['Province', 'Number'];
        foreach ($data_dealer as $key => $value) {
            $array[++$key] = [$value->province, $value->number];
        }

        if(request('search')){
            $dealers = Dealer::where('dealer_name', 'like', '%'.request('search').'%')
            ->orWhere('address', 'like', '%'.request('search').'%')->paginate(20);
        }

        $user       = Customer::latest()->get();

        // dd(json_encode($array));
        return view('dashboard.dealer.index', compact('dealers', 'count_dealers','user'))
            ->with('course', json_encode($array));
    }
```

My Blade View

```
<div class="card-body">
   <div id="pie_dealer" style="height: 300px;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var analytics = <?php echo $course; ?>

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
        var options = {
            title: 'Presentase Persebaran',
            pieHole: 0.4,
            style: {
                font: 'bold 15px "Open Sans", sans-serif'
            }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_dealer'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Showing in Localhost
[Pie chart showing in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg9Kc.png)

Not Showing in Hosting
[Pie chart not showing in hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I3P0.png)

Here my console
All data has been received, but did not succeed in making a chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var analytics = [["Province","Number"],["Bali","4"],["Banten","1"],["DKI Jakarta","2"],["Jawa Barat","2"],["Jawa Tengah","2"],["Jawa Timur","11"],["Kalimantan Barat","1"],["Kalimantan Timur","2"],["Kalimantan Utara","1"],["Kepulauan Bangka Belitung","1"],["Maluku Utara","3"],["NTB","6"],["NTT","4"],["Papua","3"],["Riau","2"],["Sulawesi Tenggara","1"],["Yogyakarta","1"]]
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
        var options = {
            title: 'Presentase Persebaran Dealer GESITS di Indonesia',
            pieHole: 0.4,
            style: {
                font: 'bold 15px "Open Sans", sans-serif'
            }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_dealer'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

[All data received, but not making chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCkO8.png)

Comment: Please share any error or console the data and check if you are getting proper data or not

Comment: I didn't find any error at all, the array data sent from the controller to the view was well received. I will add console in my question